# Batch file to write for-variables into other files

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, variables

I am trying to write a batch file that will create other, more complex batch files.

This is a portion of my script for right now:

```
(
    echo @echo off
    echo for /f "delims=" %%a in (themeset.txt) do set color=%%a&goto setcolor
    echo :setcolor
    echo color %%color%%
    echo pause
) >otherfile.cmd
```

Theoretically, the output should be a .cmd file with these exact contents:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (themeset.txt) do set color=%%a&goto setcolor
:setcolor
color %color%
pause
```

However, the batch file does not run, and when I attempted to double the %% signs it does not write the entire line correctly.

Any suggestions or solutions would be appreciated.

Max

Comment: in the line ` echo for /f "delims=" %%a in (themeset.txt) do set color=%%a&goto setcolor
` each `%%a` should be `%%%%a`. each `)` should be `^)` and `&` should be `^&`

Answer (score 0):

Magoo's comment beat me to most of the issues.

1. There is a mostly obscure situation where `ECHO text to echo` fails, so many people switched to `ECHO.text to echo`.  But somewhere along the way I hit an even more obscure line where that failed, and discovering that semicolon didn't have that problem, I switched to `ECHO;text to echo`. Which so far, I've not seen any issues.
2. The `FOR /F` command has issues, with `EOL` defaulting to the semicolon being one of them.  Some web-page out there made the claim that `DELIMS` was executed before `EOL`, so setting `EOL` to the same as `DELIMS` would disable it.  In my testing it does.  But now if we want the whole line, it seems that `TOKENS=*` disables `DELIMS`.  As far as I know, this is true, but I will admit that I haven't tested that one as much as I would like, so it is probably best to set `DELIMS=~`, or to similar character that isn't likely to be found in the file.
3. The `%` has to be escaped with another percent as in `%%`, but `FOR` requires `%%`, so now you need 4 percents `%%%%` total.
4. `%%~aa`, `%%~dd`, `%%~ff`, `%%~nn`, `%%~pp`, `%%~ss`, `%%~tt`, `%%~xx`, and `%%~zz` are all ambiguous.  So it probably best to use only capital letters with `FOR` variables, and probably safest to use only these letters: `%%B`, `%%C`, `%%E`, `%%G`, `%%H`, `%%I`, `%%J`, `%%K`, `%%L`, `%%M`, `%%O`, `%%Q`, `%%R`, `%%U`, `%%V`, `%%W`, and `%%Y` See the bottom sections of the help produced by `FOR /?` for more info on this.
5. Use the caret to escape special characters.  This page, [Escape using caret(^)](https://riptutorial.com/batch-file/example/32077/escape-using-caret---), gives some useful info, but its **NOT** complete.  You **NEED** the caret before the closing parentheses `^)`, which that page fails to tell you.  And to play it safe, I also caret the opening parentheses `^(`.  But the good thing about that page is that it does points out that when DelayedExpansion is on, you have to double escape the exclamation mark `^^!`.

Most of the rest is conventions, I normally capitalize all commands and place a colon in front of all labels, both `GOTO :Label` and `CALL :Label`.

The following code:

```
@ECHO OFF
(
    ECHO;@ECHO OFF
    ECHO;FOR /F "EOL=~ TOKENS=* DELIMS=~" %%%%L IN ^(themeset.txt^) DO SET Color=%%%%L^&GOTO :SetColor
    ECHO;:SetColor
    ECHO;Color %%Color%%
    ECHO;PAUSE
) >otherfile.cmd
```

Producted the following file:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "EOL=~ TOKENS=* DELIMS=~" %%L IN (themeset.txt) DO SET Color=%%L&GOTO :SetColor
:SetColor
Color %Color%
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0):

It is clear from your code that you are not even performing the task in the most efficient manner. The following example will therefore perform the same task, but using another methodology. *(i.e. retrieve the first line of the text file content and use it as the color command parameter from another Windows Command Script)*

```sh
@(  Echo @Set /P "colr=" 0^< "themeset.txt"
    Echo @Color %%colr%%
    Echo @Pause) 1> "otherfile.cmd"
```